# Random segmentation faults?

Tags: c++, qt

***Note, problem has been identified, refer to second section for current detail and the third section for the most likely reason and a question on how to remedy it***

I'm writing a program in Qt and I stopped a couple days ago at a segmentation fault problem. It seemed to complain about memory not being allocated. I searched around and couldn't figure out why there was an allocation problem and I took a break. Now, looking at it again, the segmentation fault is still there, but it's in a completely different, mostly unrelated function. What could be causing these random segmentation faults?

For some concreteness, in this case, I am currently getting a segmentation fault here:

```
Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR inline int QSize::height() const
{ return ht; }
```

I was getting it here before I commented out the lines (the last three lines)

```
qDebug() << QString("---SETTINGS DEBUG---")+QString("\r\n")<<
            "netProcPage: "+netProcPage.url()+"\r\n" <<
            "mapSize.width(): "+QString::number(mapSize.width())+"\r\n"<<
            "mapSize.height(): "+QString::number(mapSize.height())+"\r\n"<<
            "mapZoom: "+QString::number(mapZoom)+"\r\n"<<
            "mappxSize.width(): "+QString::number(mappxSize.width())+"\r\n"<<
            "mappxSize.height(): "+QString::number(mappxSize.height())+"\r\n"<<
            "UserCoords[0]: "+QString::number(UserCoords[0])+"\r\n"<<
            "UserCoords[1]: "+QString::number(UserCoords[1])+"\r\n"<<
            "mapCoordOffsets[0]: "+QString::number(mapCoordOffsets[0])+"\r\n"<<
            "mapCoordOffsets[1]: "+QString::number(mapCoordOffsets[1])+"\r\n"<<
            "getWindowSize.width(): "+QString::number(getWindowSize.width())+"\r\n"<<
            "getWindowSize.height(): "+QString::number(getWindowSize.height())+"\r\n"<<
            "mappxOffsets[0]: "+QString::number(mappxOffsets[0])+"\r\n"<<
            "mappxOffsets[1]: "+QString::number(mappxOffsets[1])+"\r\n"<<
            QString("---END SETTINGS DEBUG---")+QString("\r\n");
```

Before then, without changing anything (just waiting a couple days and a couple restarts later), it was here:

```
mkeMap.genMap(QString("Map1"), tempmapSize, tempmapZoom, mapDisp->ui);
```

In the `MainWindow` class constructor complaining about tempmapSize, which is defined by:

```
QSize tempmapSize;
tempmapSize = settings->mapSize; //<--- The error might be coming from here, is there an alternative?
```

which is where the segmentation faults have been associated with. This is the settings class:

```
#include "settings.h"

Settings::Settings(QWidget *parent)
{

    netProcPage = "http://localhost:81";

    // Max image size is 32767x32767 pixels (divided by 4*mapZoom since 4 panes are used at mapZoom zoom)
    // If max mapZoom is 20, max size of map is 409x409, or 408x408 to keep it even
    mapSize.setWidth(250);
    mapSize.setHeight(250);

    mapZoom = 10;
    mappxSize.setWidth(mapSize.width()*mapZoom);
    mappxSize.setHeight(mapSize.height()*mapZoom);

    //downloadMap(netProcPage,"getMap","Username","Password");
    //makeMap("bingbong",mapSize,mapZoom);
    UserCoords[0] = 0;
    UserCoords[1] = 0;
    mapCoordOffsets[0] = UserCoords[0] + .5 * mapSize.width();
    mapCoordOffsets[1] = UserCoords[1] + .5 * mapSize.height();
    //getWindowSize.setWidth(parent->width());
    //getWindowSize.setHeight(parent->height());
    getWindowSize.setWidth(500);
    getWindowSize.setHeight(500);
    mappxOffsets[0] = UserCoords[0]*mapZoom + .5 * getWindowSize.width() - .5 * mappxSize.width();
    mappxOffsets[1] = UserCoords[1]*mapZoom + .5 * getWindowSize.height() - .5 * mappxSize.height();
}

void Settings::debug()
{
    qDebug() << QString("---SETTINGS DEBUG---")+QString("\r\n")<<
                "netProcPage: "+netProcPage.url()+"\r\n" <<
                "mapSize.width(): "+QString::number(mapSize.width())+"\r\n"<<
                "mapSize.height(): "+QString::number(mapSize.height())+"\r\n"<<
                "mapZoom: "+QString::number(mapZoom)+"\r\n"<<
                "mappxSize.width(): "+QString::number(mappxSize.width())+"\r\n"<<
                "mappxSize.height(): "+QString::number(mappxSize.height())+"\r\n"<<
                "UserCoords[0]: "+QString::number(UserCoords[0])+"\r\n"<<
                "UserCoords[1]: "+QString::number(UserCoords[1])+"\r\n"<<
                "mapCoordOffsets[0]: "+QString::number(mapCoordOffsets[0])+"\r\n"<<
                "mapCoordOffsets[1]: "+QString::number(mapCoordOffsets[1])+"\r\n"<<
                "getWindowSize.width(): "+QString::number(getWindowSize.width())+"\r\n"<<
                "getWindowSize.height(): "+QString::number(getWindowSize.height())+"\r\n";//<<
                //"mappxOffsets[0]: "+QString::number(mappxOffsets[0])+"\r\n"<<
                //"mappxOffsets[1]: "+QString::number(mappxOffsets[1])+"\r\n"<<
                //QString("---END SETTINGS DEBUG---")+QString("\r\n");
}

QSize* Settings::getmapSize()
{
    return &mapSize;
}

int Settings::getmapZoom()
{
    return mapZoom;
}
```

---

### ---

### Here's the problem (identified)

I've refactored the code as suggested and I have pinpointed the exact problem, but I don't know how to fix it.

```
void makeMap::genMap(QString name, QPointF* inSize, int* zoom, Ui::MapDisp* ui)
{
    QVector<QString> mapvector;
    QPointF mapSize = *inSize; // <--- The problem is right here

...
}
```

The problem occurs when dereferencing the `QPointF` object found in an earlier instance of `Settings`, which was sent to `genMap(...)`.

The call was done like this:

```
QPointF* tempmapSize;
tempmapSize = settings->getmapSize();
int* tempmapZoom = settings->getmapZoom();
mkeMap.genMap(QString("Map1"), tempmapSize, tempmapZoom, mapDisp->ui);
```

Wherever I moved the dereference (`*Settings::inSize*`, or `*inSize`), that's where the error occurred (in the debugger). Everything has been compiling fine.

When running the program, it crashes with this error:

```
Starting C:\program-debug.exe...
ASSERT failure in QVector<T>::operator[]: "index out of range", file ../../../../../Qt/5.2.0/mingw48_32/include/QtCore/qvector.h, line 369
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
C:\program-debug.exe exited with code 3
```

This reference to `QVector<T>` is referring to later in `genMap`,

```
void makeMap::genMap(QString name, QPointF* inSize, int* zoom, Ui::MapDisp* ui)
{
    QVector<QString> mapvector;
    QPointF mapSize = *inSize; //<---Here's the segmentation fault
    /* Using this instead of the above works, as well as replacing zoom which causes another segmentation fault when dereferenced
    QPointF mapSize;
    mapSize.setX(250);
    mapSize.setY(250);
    int zoom0 = 10;
    */

    QFile file(name+"_"+QString::number(mapSize.x())+"x"+QString::number(mapSize.y())+".rtsmap");
    file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text);
    QTextStream out(&file);
    mapvector.resize(mapSize.x() * mapSize.y());
    for(int x = 0; x < mapSize.x(); x++){
        for(int y = 0; y < mapSize.y(); y++){
            uint decimalcolor = (((qSin(x)+1) + (qSin(y)+1))/4)>1?16777215:(((qSin(x)+1) + (qSin(y)+1))/4)*16777214;
            QString hexadecimalcolor;
            hexadecimalcolor.setNum(decimalcolor,16);
            mapvector[index(x, y, mapSize)] = "#" + hexadecimalcolor;
            //drawRect(x*10,y*10,10,10,"#"+hexadecimalcolor,zoom);
            out << "#" << hexadecimalcolor+'\n';
        }
    }
    file.close();
    drawMap(mapvector,zoom0,ui,mapSize);
}
```

---

---

### In Short

I think the problem is a dangling pointer. More specifically, when I pass the settings pointer to the class constructor, here:

```
MapCtrl::MapCtrl(QWidget *parent, Settings *settingsIn) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MapCtrl)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    mapDisp = new MapDisp(parent, settingsIn);
    addMap();
    settings = settingsIn;
}
```

The pointer `settingsIn` probably gets deleted at the end of the constructor with `settings` still pointing there, so later when I dereference a value from `settings`, it doesn't exist, causing a segmentation fault. So, the question is, how do I prevent the pointer called `settingsIn` from getting deleted at the end of the constructor?

---

***requested code***

Here's where the `MapCtrl` construtor `MapCtrl::MapCtrl` gets invoked and `Settings` is instantiated:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    wScr = new WelcomeScreen(this);
    Settings *settings = new Settings(this);
    mapCtrl = new MapCtrl(parent,settings);
    ...
}
```

---

***solution (thanks to Kuba Ober for the guidance and the plethora of useful C++ knowledge)***

In addition to checking for dangling pointers and fixing some possible causes, the final step was to change this:

```
MapCtrl::MapCtrl(QWidget *parent, Settings *settingsIn) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MapCtrl)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    mapDisp = new MapDisp(parent, settingsIn);
    addMap();
    qDebug() << "bingbong!!" << settingsIn->mapSize.x();
    settings = settingsIn;

}
```

to this:

```
MapCtrl::MapCtrl(QWidget *parent, Settings *settingsIn) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MapCtrl)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    mapDisp = new MapDisp(parent, settingsIn);

    qDebug() << "bingbong!!" << settingsIn->mapSize.x();
    settings = settingsIn;
    addMap();
}
```

`settings` was being set after a function that needed `settings` to be set.

Comment: If you can compile it on Linux, run it under Valgrind.

Comment: There is not near enough information here to give a useful answer.  You could ask about techniques to try, though.

Comment: This usually happens when you have a memory corruption. This is usually caused by modifying memory using a [dangling pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer)

Comment: As a confirmation, when you call a variable from a pointer like this `objpointer->var1`, if `var1` was defined by something like `type var1;` in the header and `var1 = value;` in the body, the value returned is a copy of the value, correct? (As opposed to a pointer to the address with the value).

Comment: Have you tried using a debbugger. segmentation fault are easy to analyze with gdb

Comment: @KubaOber You're completely right. The issue is `mapSize` cannot be dereferenced without causing a segmentation fault, so when it's being passed to `index()`, it most likely is because of that exactly, so that should explain the crash error. I noticed the same thing applies to a `*zoom` line in genMap, which I just realized also uses a `QVector` (it's similar to drawMap). So, when I call `genMap(QString name, QPointF* inSize, int* zoom, Ui::MapDisp* ui)` and then I dereference either `int* zoom` or `QPointF* inSize`, it gives me a segmentation fault.

Comment: Can you show how you declared `settings`, please? Also, putting breakpoints along the program may show if `setting`s is a dangling pointer. Last, switching to values like recommendeded is a good idea. You can detect value changes with signals/slots, or you can redirect the call to `Settings`'s getters

Comment: I mean, `settingsIn` declaration, ie the instanciation of `MapCtrl`'s constructor. Also, I suggest you replace `settings = settingsIn` by `settings(settingsIn)` in the constructor initialization (and not at the end of it), in case `settings` is used in `addMap()`

Comment: "So, the question is, how do I prevent the pointer called settingsIn from getting deleted at the end of the constructor?" The constructor *has nothing to do with it*. Whatever pointer you pass *into* the constructor becomes dangling. The value that you point to when the constructor is invoked, becomes destroyed. **That's why I said pass everything by value, it completely sidesteps this problem**. If you don't have the discipline to ensure that variables with live pointers to them stay accessible, use values. You can't eat your cake and have it too!

Comment: Yeah, exactly. As soon as the constructor is done running, the pointer gets destroyed. I need it to remain a pointer, otherwise I have to copy the value and if I want to change settings from another class, I cannot. So, I'm trying to find a way to only reference the pointer, except when reading or changing values. Is there no way? That doesn't make much sense to me. I can't initialize the class twice, as those would be different settings running the same program.

Comment: Seriously? I just tested to make sure the pointer was getting passed to the `MapCtrl` constructor fine and it is; in the `MapCtrl` constructor, I can read all of the settings. You're right it's getting deleted, but it gets deleted without `MapCtrl` being destroyed, so I'm thinking it's right after the constructor is done running. When else would it be?

Comment: You've just answered your own question. Congratulations. Look at the code that runs *after* `MapCtrl` is constructed, *in the method that calls that constructor*. As I've said, everything indicates that you allocate Settings not on the heap, but as a local variable. Then, the closing brace of the code where `MapCtrl::MapCtrl` was called, destructs the local instance of Settings, and boom. **As I've said, post the code where you invoke `MapCtrl` and the code that creates the instance of `Settings`**!

Comment: That's exactly what I said!! Lol, I think you're misunderstanding me. I sorta answered it -- I found why it's being caused, but I don't know how to preserve the settings class instantiation throughout the entire program if the value it's pointing to just gets deleted. I'll post the code that invokes `MapCtrl` and instantiates `Settings`

Comment: Excellent. Now change `Settings * settings = new Settings(this); mapCtrl = new MapCtrl(parent,settings);` to `mapCtrl = new MapCtrl(parent, new Settings)`. Don't worry about the memory leak. You're now guaranteeing that only `MapCtrl` gets the pointer, so nobody will delete it from under it.

Comment: @KubaOber Good point. I changed the call to create a new `Settings` class as you specified, but the problem is still exactly the same; the instance gets destroyed after the `MapCtrl` constructor (I assume, as it gets passed and is readable in the `MapCtrl` constructor), but in a later call, the value held in `MapCtrl` is no longer pointing to an object.

Comment: @JVE999 Add a `qDebug() << "bye cruel world";` to `~Settings()`, set a breakpoint there, run it in the debugger. You'll then know exactly when it gets destructed. Also, make sure you set the `settings` member of `MapCtrl` in an initializer list in the constructor, and change the `MapCtrl::settings` declaration to `Settings * const settings`.

Comment: @KubaOber Wow, that's a great tip. I appreciate it. I think I just found the error. I called a function in the `MapCtrl` constructor before I set the class settings variable to the pointer, so it gets called before it's set. I don't think it was the only problem, but fixing this with the other issues allows it to run fine.

Comment: So, `addMap()` used the `settings` member, but it was dangling? Well, that's what you get for not using initializer lists, or at least not using smart pointers. With a smart pointer, the initial value would have been zero, and `addMap` would have cleanly crashed on a null pointer dereference. It'd have been dead obvious which pointer was null. I admit that I missed that call, it should have raised some alarm bells :)

Comment: I should use smart pointers then, although I don't know much about them. Are they simple to implement? I would rather it cleanly crash than mysteriously crash.

Comment: @JVE999 Sure. Don't give `Settings` any parents. Then use `QSharedPointer<Settings> settings` within `MapCtrl`, and in any other class where you want to retain that pointer. The shared pointer would be null until you `reset` it to the correct value. So, test it with your still broken `MapCtrl` constructor that does the `addMap` call before `settings` pointer is set. Change the declaration in the class to `QSharedPointer<Settings> settings`, and the assignment to `settings.reset(settingsIn)`. You'll see that `addMap()` crashes and leads you straight to your error!

Answer (score 3):

In your entire codebase:

1. Get rid of places where you return Qt containers (`QSize`, `QList`, etc.) by pointer, and replace them with returning them by value.
2. Declare accessor methods const.

   E.g. change `Settings::getmapSize()` to the below, idiomatic, code:

   ```
   QSize Settings::getmapSize() const
   {
       return mapSize;
   }
   ```
3. Use `QPointF` for coordinates, instead of naked arrays. Pass those into methods/functions by either value or const reference; the former may actually work a tad faster on modern hardware and compilers.

   E.g. change the code in the constructor to be like this:

   ```
   mapCoordOffsets = UserCoords + (toPoint(mapSize) * .5);
   ```

   Where

   ```
   static QPointF toPoint(const QSize & size) {
     return QPointF(size.width(), size.height());
   }
   ```
4. Get rid of the C-style output parameters, like in

   ```
   void makeMap::genMap(..., QPointF* inSize, int* zoom, ...)
   ```

   If you're returning something, simply return a structure that's called, say `MapParams` or somesuch:

   ```
   MapParams makeMap::genMap(...);
   ```

   If you're taking a structure and potentially modifying it, just modify it and return the modified one:

   ```
   MapParams makeMap::genMap(..., MapParams params) {
      ...
      params.size = ...;
      params.zoom = ...;
      ...
      return params;
   }
   ```

   My worry is that somewhere you're passing a bogus pointer or otherwise a pointer is obfuscating a lifetime issue. Naked pointers in modern C++ are highly suspect, and your code seems to use a lot of them for no good reason at all. Output parameters implemented with pointers are C-ism that has no place in modern C++.
5. Another common bug could be this: you have a Settings * settings member in the MainWindow class. Then you happily create a `Settings *` local variable in `MainWindow` constructor, but the `MainWindow::settings` member remains uninitialized. That's why you should always prepend member names with `m_`, so that they are harder to confuse with local variables. Ideally, you should use initializer lists to initialize members in a constructor.

When doing debugging, when you see an assert about out-of-bounds access, you need to debug its cause. A debugger should stop on such an assert, if not then you've got something misconfigured (what's your exact platform and toolset?). Whatever happens afterwards is meaningless if it was a write access, as memory has been overwritten, and you're chasing squirrels at this point.

Doing those things cuts down a whole bunch of errors that you've possibly made in your code. It may not fix your problem, but will get you on a good trajectory towards the solution.

Comment: Thanks, I refactored everything as suggested and updated with more specific detail. Thanks! I realized I should just use QPointF for everything as it makes it less prone to error and easier to do.

Comment: It's Qt Creator 3 based on Qt 5.2.0 with MinGW 32 bit. I've pinpointed the exact location of the segmentation fault. It happens when I dereference a pointer from the `settings` class. The reason I use a pointer is to make it easy to change, rather than copying the value, which I think is the alternative. Whenever I dereference `settings->variable*`, it seems I get a segmentation fault.

Comment: I see you're saying that instead of Settings being destroyed at the end of the `MapCtrl` constructor, it's being destroyed at the end of the `MainWindow` constructor (or `MyWindow` for this example). Still, the problem is the same. I need to find a way to maintain the specific instance of `Settings` remains the same exact object and pass it around.

Comment: @JVE999 since you've posted your code, #5 is not a possibility in this exact form anymore./